# Problema con eventos JS y MagnificPOPUP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, magnific-popup

Tengo un problemilla a la hora de ejecutar unos eventos cuando el plugin de magnific-popup tiene una imagen abierta. Os pongo un poco en situación:

### Objetivo

Lo que necesito es poner impedimentos para que se capturen las imágenes de un sitio web. Soy totalmente consciente de la imposibilidad de realizar esto al 100%, aun así quiero poner ciertos impedimentos para los usuarios más básicos. Dejando de lado el resto de maneras que existen para robar una imagen, la implementación que quiero realizar consta de:

- Evitar clik derecho en imagenes (Lo tengo).
- Evitar capturar pantalla (Aquí tengo el problema parcialmente).

### Problema

Actualmente dispongo del código desarrollado, el único problema viene cuando hay que ejecutar el trigger al mismo tiempo que la foto está agrandada con magnific-popup.

Este es el código JS que dispongo:

```
function fakeCopy(){
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  aux.setAttribute("value", "Lo sentimos, no esta permitido tomar capturas de pantalla de este sitio web.");
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    if(ev.target.tagName == 'IMG'){
        ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('Ejecuto');
    return false;
    }
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 44){
    console.log('Ejecuto');
        fakeCopy();
    }
});
```

Esta porción de código corresponde a los dos eventos que ejecuto (uno para evitar click derecho y otro para evitar que se pulse esa tecla). El resto del código entiendo que es indiferente, no obstante me indicáis si necesitáis alguna porción más.

### Reproducción

Cuando se ejecutan los eventos sin que magnific-popup esté abierto, funcionan los dos correctamente.

Cuando se ejecutan los eventos con magnific-popup abierto, solo funciona el evento de click derecho, el de capturar tecla no funciona. Aquí está un poco la duda que tengo, si el evento de click derecho es correctamente capturado y ejecutado, ¿por que el otro no?.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxaqWr

Muchas gracias anticipadas, un saludo.

Comment: No encuentro ningún motivo para que no funcione, tendrías que añadir más código o incluir un [codepen](https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/aKwxt) o similar para reproducir el problema. Es posible que haya otro código que capture el mismo evento y no permita que "suba"?

Comment: Hola Pablo, cierto que al hacer lo de CodePen me ha ayudado a identificar que el problema no está en el evento, si no en la función fakeCopy(), estaba obstinado con el evento pero el trigger se ejecuta y entra en la función. El problema está en la función que copia el texto al portapapeles para copiarla justo después de la foto. Edito el post original agregando está función, además adjunto el CodePen. ¿Puede estar el problema al hacer "focus" al input mientras está el popup abierto". Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: No puedo reproducir el escenario tal cual desde Ubuntu, parece que el navegador no se entera cuando se pulsa "Print Screen" porque el sistema operativo captura el evento antes (así que advierto que no funcionará en Linux)

Comment: He probado a quitar la condición que comprueba la tecla y siempre se ejecuta correctamente el fakeCopy, lo siento pero no puedo ayudarte con tu problema, a ver si alguien con Windows se anima...

Comment: Perfecto Pablo, ya tenemos claro a parte del problema concreto que este código no funcionará en Linux, quizás luego desde casa con linux me anime a hacer más pruebas, de momento sigo intentando solucionarlo para Windows. Muchas gracias por las molestias que te has tomado. Un saludo

Comment: Por cierto @PabloLozano si pulsas la tecla sin el popup abierto, ¿se ejecuta la condición?

Comment: He probado con la imagen aumentada y en icono y siempre se ejecuta el listener y fakeCopy

Comment: He encontrado esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132605, quizás te sea útil.